# How to do the following in VB: Last date of Month

Tags: vb.net, date

How to do the following in VB: display the last date of the month (in format of dd/mm/yyyy) unless current date is the third last day of the month. if that is the case display the third working day of the next month.

What I have been trying to do:

use a if condition

```
Now.day = Datetime.DaysInMonth(now.year,now.month)-3 AND
Not Now.Adddays(3).Dayofweek.ToString.ToUpper.Equals(“SUNDAY”) AND
Not Now.Adddays(3).Dayofweek.ToString.ToUpper.Equals(“SATURDAY”)

New Datetime(now.year,
now.month,
NOT (New  
Datetime(now.year,now.addmonth(1),1).Day)+3)).Dayofweek.ToString.ToUpper
.Equals(“SUNDAY”)
OR
NOT New Datetime(now.year,
now.month,
(New 
Datetime(now.year,now.addmonth(1),1).Day)+3))
.Dayofweek.ToString.ToUpper.Equals(“SATURDAY”)

in_strdate = New Datetime(now.year,
now.month,
(New Datetime(now.year,now.addmonth(1),1).Day)+3)).ToString(“dd/MM/yyyy”)

in_strdate = New Datetime(now.year,
now.month,
(New Datetime(now.year,now.addmonth(1),1).Day)+5)).ToString(“dd/MM/yyyy”)

New Datetime(now.year, now.Addmonths(-1).month, 
Datetime.Daysinmonth(now.year,now.addmonths(-1).month))
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have already tried?

Comment: Please see updated post

Comment: By "third last day of the month", do you mean _working_ day, or any day?

Comment: The third last day is any day, working day or not

Comment: And is "third last" the day that has three days after it, or is it the first of the last three days of the month, as in third from last, second from last, last?

Comment: The descriptions for the VB.NET and VBA tags specifically state that they are not to be used for questions on the other language.  Don't add a tags that are not relevant to the question.